# uniform convergence on bounded sets vs un bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

For the function $f_k(x) = \chi_{[-k,k]}$ then we have that $f_k$ increases to the constant function $f(x) = 1 \forall x$. I am confused by the statement:

convergence is uniform on any bounded set and fails to be uniform on any unbounded set. What exactly does this mean?

I understand that the bounded set in this case is the sequence of sets $[-k,k]$ and the unbounded sets are $\mathbb{R} -[k,k]$, but i don't understand thinking about convergence on different parts of the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "convergence is uniform on any bounded set and fails to be uniform on any unbounded set".

It means the following: if $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb R$, with $X$ bounded and $Y$ unbounded, then $(f_k|_X)_k$ converges uniformly to $f|_X$ and $(f_k|_Y)_k$ does not converge uniformly to $f|_Y$.

Comment: So the restriction of $\chi$ to the bounded set $[-k,k]$ then for all $\epsilon > 0, \forall n$ we have $|\chi |_{[-k,k]} -1| = |1-1| = 0$ whereas in the unbounded restriction the difference is always $1$ ? is that correct?

Comment: That's the idea! However, you must do it for **any** bounded set, not only for the sets $[-k,k]$.